# BLT2.z installation

Tags: make

I'm trying to install BLT2.4z, with Tcl/tk8.4. When I run command `make` I see this:

```
(cd src; make all) gcc -c -Wall -O6   -I. -I.  -I/Users/scarter/tk8.4.20/unix/include -I/Users/scarter/tcl8.4.20/unix/include bltAlloc.c
error: invalid value '6' in '-O6' make[1]: *** [bltAlloc.o] Error 1
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

There are six optimization levels you can give to `gcc`: `-O`, `-O0`, `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3` and `-Os`. The makefile you are using tries to give `-O6` as an argument to `gcc`, which is not supported. So probably you want to replace `-O6` with `-O3`, if you want highly optimized binary, or maybe `-O1`, which slightly optimizes the binary.

Comment: Hey thanks...now i'm seeing gcc -c -Wall -O2   -I. -I.  -I/Users/scarter/tk8.4.20/unix/include -I/Users/scarter/tcl8.4.20/unix/include bltAlloc.c
In file included from bltAlloc.c:1:
In file included from ./bltInt.h:41:
/Users/scarter/tk8.4.20/unix/include/tk.h:77:11: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file
      not found
#       include <X11/Xlib.h>
                ^
Any ideas?

Comment: @user3011008 Install X11 development packages (e.g. `libx11-dev`, the package name depends on the distribution). You may need other packages as well, check the installation instructions (often there's a file called `INSTALL` at the root of the source tree, if not try `README` or other files that aren't source code).

Comment: Do you know where I can download libX11-dev for Unix? I am not sure where to find it!....

Comment: @user3011008 Do as @Gilles said: search for `libx11-dev` from your package managers package listing. And as he also pointed out: notice that the name may vary between different linux distributions.